# Wordpress Admin with express and node api

Tags: mysql, node.js, wordpress

I'm planning to use **Docker** `containers` to create complex **admin** and `API` for listing web / mobile app, I am gonna use one WordPress container as application admin part due to `WordPress` has great custom post and media library capability, and create `node` **microservices** to query directly from `MySQL` and expose `express` `API`, finally I will create react front-end and mobile app that consumes this `api`.

The reason I use `WordPress` because `WordPress` admin UI and `media-library` are awesome.

The reason I chose `express` node `microservice` instead of `WordPress` because `WordPress` `query` is slow.

Please tell me is this `architecture` is a good solution. or their anything I can use instead of this.

Comment: I beg to differ. Building a complicated node app on top of Wordpress is not ideal. Either just use PHP or use a CMS built with Node.

Answer (score 1):

Though this isn't the best architecture as per your requirement, you can use WordPress as a CMS for your application. However, I suggest using any CMS that is built on top of NodeJS and create complex admin

Comment: May i know the reason why should I avoid using wordpress as micro service for node?